# Substract two row values in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

Currently I have a sort of dataframe where I want to substract value from current row from the previous one.

example:
df = pd.Datafame([1,4,3,5,6],columns = ["time")])

| left |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

I want to iterate over these rows and store it in a list. So the list will get like this [-3,1,-2,-1].

So far I have this

```
 list = []
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
          list.append(row['time'])
```

Now the for loop just stores the values in the list when it comes across the row. How can I change it that it substracts the current value from the previous one and stores it in a list?

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df['time'].diff(-1).tolist()[:-1]
>>> [-3.0, 1.0, -2.0, -1.0]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! One more question. How can I access the list, because when I look at the list (that I created in the code) it is empty?

Comment: The code, which I shared, produced the list that you need.

Comment: Just one more question. Is it also possible to get the difference in percentage instead of just the difference between the two values. So instead of 3 you store (4-1/4) = 0.75?

Comment: I also made one small mistake. Instead of a list with -3, 1, -2 and -1, I want a list the other way around, so 3,-1,2 and 1

Comment: If you need the data in the opposite order, you can use `df['time'].diff(1).tolist()[1:]`. As for the percentage, you can do it manually: `df['time'].diff(1).tolist()[1:] / df['time'][1:]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.shift(-1)`:

`df['time'] = df['left'] - df['left'].shift(-1)`

or if you need it as a list:

`(df['left'] - df['left'].shift(-1)).tolist()`